# Jmeter webdriver wait funtion - Can not create new object with constructor org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait with the passed arguments

Tags: selenium-webdriver, jmeter, selenium-chromedriver, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0

I am trying to use the JMeter Selenium Webdriver wait function but getting error output as -javax.script.ScriptException: TypeError: Can not create new object with constructor org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait with the passed arguments; they do not match any of its method signatures. in  at line number 2

<kbd>var ui = JavaImporter(org.openqa.selenium.support.ui)
var wait = new ui.WebDriverWait(WDS.browser,120)</kbd>

Code in the webdriver sampler:

```
var ui = JavaImporter(org.openqa.selenium.support.ui)
var wait = new ui.WebDriverWait(WDS.browser,120)
WDS.sampleResult.sampleStart()
WDS.browser.get('http://jmeter-plugins.org')
WDS.sampleResult.sampleEnd()
```

I am using the latest version of Jmeter (5.5) and the latest selenium webdriver support package (4.5.1). This use to work before. Can someone help here please? thanks!!

I have tried upgrading and degrading the Jmeter, but no luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WebDriver Sampler 4.5.1 comes bundled with [selenium-support 4.5.0](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-support/4.5.0) and [WebDriverWait constructor](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-support/4.5.0/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/WebDriverWait.html) for this version expects 2nd argument to be [Duration](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html) object

So you need to do something like:

```
var wait = new ui.WebDriverWait(WDS.browser, java.time.Duration.ofSeconds(120))
```

Also be informed that [since JMeter 3.1 it's recommended to use Groovy language for scripting](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) mainly for [performance reasons](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy) so you might want consider switching, it would be way easier to debug your test.